# Algolia autocomplete pass in options

Tags: algolia

How do you pass in the options object when using the angular library?

The sample is clear from the docs but unlike the jquery example there is no autocomplete object you have access to when initializing to pass in the object.

Instead it uses the `$scope.$on`. Where could you pass in `{ debug: true }`?

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/algoliasearch/3/algoliasearch.angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/autocomplete.js/0/autocomplete.angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  angular.module('myApp', ['algoliasearch', 'algolia.autocomplete'])
    .controller('yourController', ['$scope', 'algolia', function($scope, algolia) {
      var client = algolia.Client('YourApplicationID', 'YourSearchOnlyAPIKey');
      var index = client.initIndex('YourIndex');

      $scope.getDatasets = function() {
        return {
          source: algolia.sources.hits(index, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
          displayKey: 'my_attribute',
          templates: {
            suggestion: function(suggestion) {
              return suggestion._highlightResult.my_attribute.value;
            }
          }
        };
      };

      $scope.$on('autocomplete:selected', function(event, suggestion, dataset) {
        console.log(suggestion, dataset);
      });
    }]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `aa-options` like describe below:

```html
<input type="search" id="aa-search-input" class="aa-input-search" placeholder="Search for players or teams..." name="search"
    autocomplete aa-datasets="getDatasets()" aa-options="{hint: false}" />
```